# Could not unmount /dev/sda1 with root filesystem

Tags: mount, disk

Could not unmount `/dev/sda1` with  root filesystem.
When I try to resize it by unmounting but the following error message pops up:

> The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:
>
> /
>
> Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points. You are advised to unmount them manually.

How to go about?

Answer (score 3):

To resize/move partitions, the best way is to boot from LiveCD/LiveUSB. Then use Gparted to manage partitions. You might need to install it, so do `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

There is a way to unmount your root partition on running system but I advise you not to do it because it is risky for your data.

Answer (score 2):

You can't unmount it, because it's being used. From the error message, `/dev/sda1` is the location of your root directory `/`. Instead, create a [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), then boot from that. Then, you should be able to resize the (now-unused) root partition.

**Make sure you back everything up before resizing!**

Answer (score -3):

You could try this:

```
sudo -i
umount /dev/sda1
```

and then this

```
mount -a /
```

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: No, it won't.  Do you ever test what you post?

Comment: You could then alter the /etc/fstab file wit sudo nano